# how to speed up: ActiveRecord hstore assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-postgresql, hstore

I have a rails app, using ActiveRecord and Postgresql.  have a field in my model called meta_data and am trying to speed up a data import routine I've built.

the model is defined as such: (I cleaned out irrelevant fields)
 == Schema Information

```
Table name: entities

id           :integer          not null, primary key
meta_data    :hstore
created_at   :datetime         not null
updated_at   :datetime         not null
```

I have 19 fields in a loader file that I use to create a hash.  then I assign the hash to the meta_data field and save it.  This algorithm is the bottleneck in my import and it's very slow.  In the process of testing I commented out the save and found it still very slow.  If i comment out the meta_data field assignment as well it is much faster so it seems that my bottleneck is in the hstore field assignment even though it's not actually calling a save or doing any sql on it.

any ideas on how to speed this up?

```
meta = {}
@demographic_fields.each do |k, v|
  meta[v] = hash[k]
end
my_object.meta_data = meta
#current_entity.save
```

If I comment out the assignment to my_object.meta_data it is fast.

Not sure what I can do.  doesn't seem to be a PG issue, more a rails/activerecord/hstore implementation issue...

thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: is `meta_data` an association of `my_object` or a field in it?

Comment: added model structure to initial post...

Comment: What do these `meta` Hashes look like? Are they crazy-big? The [hstore-to-string](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/cast.rb#L38) stuff that AR uses is pretty simple.

Comment: There are 19 fields in the hash.  nothing too big.  They are just properties of hospitals in a database.  things like State, id numbers, county, company names, integer values (of course these are represented by strings in the hstore)... but nothing hugs by any stretch.  just 19 values.  another note though: this is in rails 3.2.12 if that has any bearing on it.  using the activerecord-postgres-hstore gem

Comment: Do you need to go through ActiveRecord for the import? AR isn't exactly a speed demon so it might make sense to talk to the database directly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do `my_object.meta_data = @demographic_fields` without the loop -- so if there is some sort of overhead involved with each assignment then you can skip it that way.